# Sharing session between two apps - Dilemmas and Approaches

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, websphere-8

This is what I want to happen.

Current Setup: Two wars deployed in Websphere v8 (App1 and App2). Both have a login feature where users enter username and password to get in the app. This is not using LDAP or JAAS, its just plain query from the db to check if username and password is correct.

Problem: There had been a move to "combine" the two apps where authenticated users in App1 can now access App2 directly without logging in and having the same session. If user accesses a module in App2 without logging, user will be directed to login page of App1 to login.

Other factors:
App1 and App2 are in the same websphere instance in the same box and in the same cell.

Question:
Is it possible to implement SSO and shared session between App1 and App2 in websphere?

Answer (score 1):

From what I read you are either performing the authentication on your own with App1 and App2, meaning without using WebSphere Security or you have both applications inside two different WebSphere Cells where no SSO is setup.

If it is option 1 I strongly recommend you to take a look at WebSphere Security and what the container provides you there.

Which brings me to option two cells without SSO
WebSphere Application server builds out by default a Cell wide SSO model. A cell means a collection of servers which are controlled together. By default WebSphere uses a token named LTPA_Token or since 6.1 LTPA_Token2. At the cell level the security is configuired which includes the SSO domain, which is in fact "just" the cookie domain. WebSphere persists the authentication state inside of the token as a cookie and the browser will submit this to the server matching to the cookie domain.

Having said that. If you have two cells you can exchange the security keys between these two and so they can both understand the security Token created by both of them. You need to ensure some additional information like realm, security domain, attached user repository.

As you mentioned App2 should send all users to App1 you probably need to define the End point to handle the Authentication within your web.xml and have it point direct to App2 or write a TAI (Trust Association Interceptor) on App2 to send all not authenticated requests to App1

In addition you could as well put an authentication proxy in front of the two applications which will only ensure the authentication state and establish the security state as the request is passed to the backend.

For reference

[WebSphere Application Server Infocenter Topic](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Setting_up_single_sign-on_for_WebSphere_Application_Server)

Comment: Hi, its more like this. Step 1 - user logs in App1. Step 2 - App1 checks db if username and password is valid. Step3 - if valid, App1 creates a session for user. Step 4 - when user accesses App2 through a link in App1, App2 will receive the same session App1 created for the user

Comment: ok but even more I would recommend you have a look at WebSphere Security. WebSphere does separate the authentication session from the HTTPSession which makes totally sense. Based on J2EE each Application gets an own Session object server side to separate the information. To minimize your effort you could build a servletfilter which copies the Security information into the HTTP session and adds additional validation checks. Then you could still have your Application running unprotected in WebSphere and only handle the authentication using an application based login.